# How to view bad blocks on mounted ext3 filesystem?

Tags: linux, ext3, fsck, badblocks

I've ran fsck -c on the (unmounted) partition in question a while ago. The process was unattended and results were not stored anywhere (except badblock inode).

Now I'd like to get badblock information to know if there are any problems with the harddrive.
Unfortunately, partition is used in the production system and can't be unmounted.

I see two ways to get what I want:

1. Run badblocks in read-only mode. This will probably take a lot of time and cause unnecessary bruden on the system.
2. Somehow extract information about badblocks from the filesystem iteself.

How can I view known badblocks registered in mounted filesystem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
dumpe2fs -b /dev/<WHATEVER>
```